# How to generate CXF beans.xml using wsdl2java maven?

Tags: cxf

When I use eclipse to generate jaxb classes and Webservice implementation by top down approach. eclipse  automatically generates csf-beans.xml. However wsdl1java maven plugin doesnot generate config file. Is there  are options available to plugin to enable generation of bean configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! There isn't any option for generating cxf configuration file with `wsdl2java` maven plugin. You can get and customize the general `cxf.xml` file from [Apache CXF Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html) and add it to the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of your web application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm ok... I use the Juno generate web service to generate web service which generates cxf bean.xml. Then switch to maven to do all the stuff

Comment: Good approach, Thanks.